# How to prevent angular-ui accordion from toggling when sorted with angular-ui's sortable

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, angular-ui-bootstrap

I made a sortable accordion with angular, angular-ui bootstrap and ui-sortable, where you can drag & drop the accordion-groups.

The problem is, that the current accordion group is toggling (open/collapse) when dropped on a new position.

Plunkr: [Click](http://plnkr.co/edit/YAGoVq?p=preview)

I can't find out how to prevent this behaviour, tried with `stopPropagation()` in the sortables option on stop, beforeStop and update functions... no change (because its referring on a event that is handled by jQuery and not Angular, i think?!).

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

After a long time, I've wrapped my head around this again. Obviously not the most elegant solution but it works for now: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8J5ZxocNzmcOtNL9mS3R?p=preview)
If you have any suggestions / corrections, don't hold back.

EDIT: based on comments, see the updated Plunker for Chrome:     [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jAY5AtnH5SE2f5aqxRGs?p=preview)

The main trick is to control the toggle using:

```
<a class="accordion-toggle" 
   ng-click="$parent.isElementDragged() || (isOpen = !isOpen)" 
   accordion-transclude="heading">
   {{heading}}
</a>
```

Comment: This doesn't work on the plunkr. You might want to update it:)

Comment: I've tested with FF and Chrome on Win7 right now and it is still working. What OS/Browser did u use?

Comment: 64bit chrome on Windows 7

Comment: @a-p can you please concrete what the issue is? don't have a 64bit system for testing.

Comment: Because of strict MIME type checking Chrome sometimes refuses to execute JS referenced via raw.github.com. Fixed it here  http://plnkr.co/edit/jAY5AtnH5SE2f5aqxRGs?p=preview